# Changing the title of a column in a PivotTable

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble changing the title of some columns in a pivot table. I'm trying to make them have dates in them. Each date 6 days further from the last.

Like this[image]

But, I cannot get an equation inside the column title to stay, every time I type in the equation and press enter, it evaluates to either `0` (If the format of the cell is number or general), or  `1/0/1990` (If formatted as a date). I checked the value of the cell by `=ISTEXT(A1)` and it evaluates as true. No matter how I format the cell. So I can never change the title to look like the picture. Any ides?

Here is what I have.
`TRUE` is the result from `ISTEXT()`

[image]

Even if I manually enter in the formula via the function arguments, it'll show up correct, but when I click ok. It will go back to either `0` or `1/0/1990`

[image]

Here's the original page
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3p8Jm7oNAo4ZUN0Qk1mR1cxYmM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel, dynamic values (formulas) in the header of a table-formatted table are not allowed.

Instead, you can first generate your table header and then format the table as (pivot-)table. You should get a message saying that the header row will be converted in static text (with correct format).

Comment: If I convert it to static text then I will lose the ability to update the first column header and have the others change. It'll lose its formula functionality. Which is the purpose of this question..

Comment: Imho, unfortunately the header row is not meant to be dynamic in excel tables.

Comment: Now I'm left wondering how the person who made the original excel sheet added that in. Lol. It works fine on theirs. I just cant figure out how they did it.

Comment: can you somehow provide a link to download the original excel sheet where the table header is still dynamically changeable?

Comment: Added in original question

Comment: The excel sheet does not contain excel-(pivot-)tables. It is just a normal excel sheet with some applied layouts (e.g. background-color) and with row-filters. When formatting it to an excel-table or generating a pivot-table of it, you will get the same problem (header will be static)